# How can I let a user change the title of a note in the nav bar of the detail view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, title, nav

I'm looking at new ways of doing things, and I was wondering how to, in a note app that is built from a Master Detail application template, let the user (in app) tap and change the title of the note in the detail view controller.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYO6F.png

So if the user taps "Note", they will be able to change the title of the note altogether.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: this is what the basic idea came in my mind so I think you can add `UIView` as subview on navigationBar with `UIbutton` and then on tap you can replace it with `UITextField` get net title from user and update.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented basic idea for this question.

You can add `UIView` as subview on `navigationBar` with `UIbutton` and then on tap you can replace it with `UITextField` get the new title from user and update.

Or this You can add single `UITextField` as titleView on `UINavigationBar` like

`self.navigationItem.titleView = youtextField;`

Hope this will help you